# Collection of Great Applications and Programs using Macros

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, racket, hygiene

I am very very interested in Macros and just beginning to understand its true power. Please help me collect some great usage of macro systems.

So far I have these constructs:

**Pattern Matching:**

> Andrew Wright and Bruce Duba. Pattern
>   matching for Scheme, 1995

**Relations in the spirit of Prolog:**

> Dorai Sitaram. Programming in schelog.
>   http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/schelog/schelog.html
>
> Daniel P. Friedman, William E. Byrd,
>   and Oleg Kiselyov. The Reasoned
>   Schemer. The MIT Press, July 2005
>
> Matthias Felleisen. Transliterating
>   Prolog into Scheme. Technical Report
>   182, Indiana University, 1985.

**Extensible Looping Constructs:**

> Sebastian Egner. Eager comprehensions
>   in Scheme: The design of SRFI-42. In
>   Workshop on Scheme and Functional
>   Programming, pages13–26, September
>   2005.
>
> Olin Shivers. The anatomy of a loop: a
>   story of scope and control. In
>   International Conference on Functional
>   Programming, pages 2–14, 2005.

**Class Systems:**

> PLT. PLT MzLib: Libraries manual.
>   Technical Report PLT-TR2006-4-v352,
>   PLT Scheme Inc., 2006.
>   http://www.plt-scheme.org/techreports/
>
> Eli Barzilay. Swindle.
>   http://www.barzilay.org/Swindle.

**Component Systems:**

> Ryan Culpepper, Scott Owens, and
>   Matthew Flatt. Syntactic abstraction
>   in component interfaces. In
>   International Conference on Generative
>   Programming and Component Engineering,
>   pages 373–388, 2005

**Software Contract Checking**

> Matthew Flatt and Matthias Felleisen.
>   Units: Cool modules for HOT languages
>   In ACM SIGPLAN Conference on
>   Programming Language Design and
>   Implementation, pages 236–248, 1998
>
> Oscar Waddell and R. Kent Dybvig.
>   Extending the scope of syntactic
>   abstraction.In Symposium on Principles
>   of Programming Languages, pages
>   203–215, 199

**Parser Generators**

> Scott Owens, Matthew Flatt, Olin
>   Shivers, and Benjamin McMullan. Lexer
>   and parser generators in Scheme. In
>   Workshop on Scheme and Functional
>   Programming, pages 41–52, September
>   2004.

**Tools for Engineering Semantics:**

> Matthias Felleisen, Robert Bruce
>   Findler, and Matthew Flatt. Semantics
>   Engineering with PLT Redex. MIT Press,
>   August 2009.

**Speciﬁcations of Compiler Transformations:**

> Dipanwita Sarkar, Oscar Waddell, and R. Kent Dybvig. A nanopass
>   framework for compiler education.
>   Journal of Functional
>   Programming,15(5):653–667, September
>   2005. Educational Pearl.

**Novel Forms of Execution**

> Servlets with serializable
>   continuations Greg Pettyjohn, John
>   Clements, Joe Marshall, Shriram
>   Krishnamurthi, and Matthias Felleisen.
>   Continuations from generalized stack
>   inspection. In International
>   Conference on Functional Programming,
>   pages216–227, 2005.

**Theorem-Proving System**

> Sebastian Egner. Eager comprehensions in Scheme: The design
>   of  SRFI-42.
>   In Workshop on Scheme and Functional Programming, pages 13–26,
>   September 2005.

**Extensions of the Base Language with Types**

> Sam Tobin-Hochstadt and Matthias
>   Felleisen.The design and
>   implementation of typed scheme. In
>   Symposium on Principles of Programming
>   Languages, pages 395–406, 2008.

**Laziness**

> Eli Barzilay and John Clements.
>   Laziness without all the hard
>   work:combining lazy and strict
>   languages for teaching. In Functional
>   and declarative programming in
>   education, pages 9–13, 2005.

**Functional Reactivity**

> Gregory H. Cooper and Shriram
>   Krishnamurthi. Embedding dynamic 
>   dataﬂow in a call-by-value language. 
>   In European Symposium on Programming,
>   2006

---

**Reference:**

Collected from [Ryan Culpepper's Dissertation](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/dissertation-culpepper.pdf)

Comment: +1 Nice question. I think it would be useful to ask it at cstheory.SE or migrate it there, because it looks like similar questions, for example [What's new in purely functional data structures since Okasaki?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1539/3124), have much more views there.

Comment: I posted it there. But I am getting downvotes.

Comment: @Yasir and kujaan, this is not a research-level question, so doesn't belong on cstheory, it might belong on programmers though

Comment: If you want _usage_ examples, it's not particularly theoretical either

Comment: Btw., why 'hygiene' tag? At least half of the listed examples are of the common lisp-style macros.

Comment: SK-logic: every macro listed above is currently implemented using hygenic macros, and almost all of them were originally implement that way (except the ones from the 80s).

Answer (score 9):

Culpepper & Felleisen, Fortifying Macros, ICFP 2010

Culpepper, Tobin-Hochstadt and Felleisen, Advanced Macrology and the Implementation of Typed Scheme, Scheme Workshop 2007

Flatt, Findler, Felleisen, Scheme with Classes, Mixins, and Traits, APLAS 2006

Herman, Meunier, Improving the Static Analysis of Embedded Languages via Partial Evaluation, ICFP 2004

Comment: "Scheme with Classes, Mixins, and Traits" was an impressive paper with very useful references. Thanks for recommending.

Answer (score 6):

Shivers, Carlstrom, Gasbichler & Sperber (1994 & later) [The Scsh Reference manual](http://www.scsh.net/docu/html/man.html).

> Has a lot of good examples of using macros to embed mini-languages into Scheme.  Introduced me to the technique of defining macros that implicitly quote their argument.  Look at the use of process forms, regular expressions, and the awk-like mini-languages.  Scsh is my recommendation as a starting point for playing with macros.

Hilsdale & Friedman (2000) [Writing Macros in Continuation-Passing Style](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Scheme2000/hilsdale.ps).

> Shows how the weak syntax-rules macros can be made powerful using continuation-passing style.  Gives plenty of examples.

Flatt, Culpepper, Darais &  Findler (submitted) [Macros that Work Together - Compile-Time Bindings, Partial Expansion, and Definition Contexts](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/jfp11-submit-fcdf.pdf).

> Provides an overview of, and semantics for the approach to macros in Racket/PLT Scheme.  Not a whole lot of examples, but I think the paper has something you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

ReadScheme! Remember to check the extensive bibliography on ReadScheme.

http://library.readscheme.org/page3.html

One example I think you missed is embedding SQL syntax into Scheme.
http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/sw2002/schemeunit-schemeql.pdf

Macros are also used to write supports for automated testing.

Answer (score 3):

Not a Scheme, but somewhat similar Lisp dialect with a very extensive use of macros: http://www.meta-alternative.net/mbase.html

There are macros implementing various kinds of pattern matching, list comprehensions, various parsers generators (including a PEG/Packrat implementation), embedded Prolog, ADT visitors inference (like scrap your boilerplate in Haskell), extensible syntax macros, Hindley-Milner type system, Scheme-like syntax macros, and many more. Parts of that functionality can be potentially ported to Scheme, other parts needs an extended macro system with explicit context.

Answer (score 2):

I would add "The Scheme standard library itself" to the list.  Look at the file `boot-9.scm` in the guile distribution.  Many of the most commonly-used Scheme forms - `case`, `and`, etc. - are defined there as macros.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://cs.northwestern.edu/~ian/grl-paper.pdf) an example of a pretty awesome use of scheme macros to create efficient robotics systems written in scheme

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly precise in so far as it is spread out over a large number of very old publications most of which i've never read, but IIRC large chunks of the Common Lisp Object System and the Meta-Object Protocol*, can be; are; or were initially, built with of macros...

*** Which compose IMHO by far the most advanced OO system programming has ever seen

Comment: This answer would be a whole lot better if you could name a particular paper as a good starting point.

Comment: I know, but all the interesting papers were written in the '70s which makes them really hard to find :(

Comment: @charles, +1, but i hoped googling the names was kinda implied as the next step ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check one of my favorites implementations of a REST API: the Slack api client, that isn't written in Scheme but it is in Racket.

[octotep/racket-slack-api](https://github.com/octotep/racket-slack-api)